# Meu jogo tetris desce uma peça e na segunda peça ele da game over

Tags: c#, unity3d, jogos

Meu jogo tetris desce a primeira peça normal, porem na segunda peça la no alto mesmo, ele da game over. Como se a segunda peça tivesse alcançado o topo entrando na condição da função GAME OVER.

Meu código do game:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int gridWidth = 10;
    public static int gridHeight = 20;
    public Tetromino[,] Grid = new Tetromino[gridWidth, gridHeight];
    private GameObject previewTetromino;
    private GameObject nextTetromino;
    private bool gameStarted = false;
    public int scoreOneLine = 40;
    public int scoreTwoLine = 100;
    public int cont = 0;
    private int numerOfRowsThisTurn = 0;
    private int currentRowMax = 0;
    public Text hud_score;
    public static int currentScore = 0;
    private Vector2 previewTetrominoPosition = new Vector2 (13.88f, 11.08f);


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        SpawnNextTetromino ();


        //AudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    } 

    void Update () {

        Checks ();
        UpdateScore ();
        UpdateUI ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void UpdateScore(){
        if (numerOfRowsThisTurn > 0) {

            if (numerOfRowsThisTurn == 1) {
                ClearedOneLine ();
            } else if (numerOfRowsThisTurn == 2) {
                ClearedTwoLine ();
            }
            numerOfRowsThisTurn = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Checks(){

        for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {

            }
        }

        /*
        for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {

                if (Grid [x, y] != null) {
                    Debug.Log ("grid : " + x + " , " + y + " nao nulo " + Grid[x,y].tag);
                    if (Grid [x, y].tag == "CARBONO") {
                        Debug.Log ("EXISTE C: ");
                        if(Grid [x, y].tag == "CARBONO")
                        if (Grid [x + 1, y] != null){

                            if (Grid [x + 1, y].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                            cont++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (Grid [x - 1, y] != null) {
                                if (Grid [x - 1, y].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                                    cont++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (Grid [x, y + 1] != null) {
                                if (Grid [x, y + 1].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                                    cont++;
                                }
                            }
                        if (Grid [x, y - 1] != null) {

                                    if (Grid [x, y - 1].tag == "HIDROGENIO") {
                                        cont++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                    Debug.Log ("contador: " + cont); //teste
                }cont = 0;
            }
        }*/
    }

    public void UpdateUI(){
        hud_score.text = currentScore.ToString ();
    }



    public void ClearedOneLine(){
        currentScore += scoreOneLine;
    }
    public void ClearedTwoLine(){
        currentScore += scoreTwoLine;
    }

    public bool CheckIsAboveGrid(Tetromino tetromino){
        for(int x = 0; x < 20; ++x){
        foreach(Transform mino in tetromino.transform){
        Vector2 pos = Round (tetromino.transform.position);
                Debug.Log ("POS Y " + pos.y);
                if(pos.y > gridHeight - 1){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsFullRowAt(int y){
        for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x){
            if(Grid[x,y] = null){
                return false;
            }
        }
        numerOfRowsThisTurn++;
        return true;
    }

    public void updateGrid (Tetromino tetromino) {
        for (int y = 0; y <gridHeight; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x <gridWidth; ++x) {
                if (Grid [x, y] != null) {
                    if (Grid [x, y].transform.parent == tetromino.transform) {
                        Grid [x, y] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (Transform mino in tetromino.transform) {
            Vector2 pos = Round (mino.position);
            if (pos.y < gridHeight) {
                mino.tag = tetromino.tag;
                Grid [(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y] = tetromino;

                //Debug.Log ("x :" + pos.x + "y: " + pos.y + "tag next tetromino : "+ mino.tag);
            }
        }
    }
    public Transform GetTransformAtGetPosition (Vector2 pos) {

        if (pos.y > gridHeight - 1) {
            return null;
        } else {
            if (Grid [(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y] == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return Grid [(int)pos.x, (int)pos.y].transform;
            }

        }

    }

    public void SpawnNextTetromino () {
        if (!gameStarted) {

            gameStarted = true;
            nextTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(GetRandomTetromino(), typeof(GameObject)), new Vector2 (5.0f, 22.0f), Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log ("tag next tetromino : "+ nextTetromino.tag);
            previewTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate (Resources.Load (GetRandomTetromino (), typeof(GameObject)), previewTetrominoPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            previewTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino> ().enabled = false;

        } else {
            previewTetromino.transform.localPosition = new Vector2 (5.0f, 20.0f);
            nextTetromino = previewTetromino;
            nextTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino> ().enabled = true;

            previewTetromino = (GameObject)Instantiate (Resources.Load (GetRandomTetromino (), typeof(GameObject)), previewTetrominoPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            previewTetromino.GetComponent<Tetromino> ().enabled = false;
        }

    }


    public bool CheckIsInsideGrid (Vector2 pos){
        return ((int)pos.x >= 0 && (int)pos.x < gridWidth && (int)pos.y >= 0);
    }

    public Vector2 Round (Vector2 pos){
        return new Vector2 (Mathf.Round(pos.x), Mathf.Round(pos.y));
    }

    string GetRandomTetromino(){
        int randomTetromino = Random.Range (1, 5);
        string randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
        switch (randomTetromino) {
        case 1:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";
            break;
        case 2:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
            break;
        case 3:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/H";
            break;
        case 4:
            randomTetrominoName = "Prefabs/C";
            break;

        }
        return randomTetrominoName;


    }

    public void updateConnection(Tetromino tetromino){
        if (tetromino.tag == "CARBONO") {

            foreach (Transform mino in tetromino.transform) {
                Vector2 pos = Round (mino.position);

                if (Grid[(int)pos.x,(int)pos.y+1] != null) {
                    tetromino.setConnection (Grid[(int)pos.x,(int)pos.y+1], Tetromino.UP);
                }

                if (pos.y != 0) {
                    if (Grid[(int)pos.x,(int)pos.y-1] != null) {
                        tetromino.setConnection (Grid[(int)pos.x,(int)pos.y-1], Tetromino.DOWN);
                    }               
                }

                if (pos.x != 0) {
                    if (Grid[(int)pos.x-1,(int)pos.y] != null) {
                        tetromino.setConnection (Grid[(int)pos.x-1,(int)pos.y], Tetromino.LEFT);
                    }
                }

                if (pos.x != gridWidth-1) {
                    if (Grid[(int)pos.x+1,(int)pos.y] != null) {
                        tetromino.setConnection (Grid[(int)pos.x+1,(int)pos.y] , Tetromino.RIGHT);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }


    public void GameOver(){
        Application.LoadLevel ("GameOver");
    }

}

segunda classe:

    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

public class Tetromino : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int UP = 1;  
    public static int DOWN = 2;
    public static int RIGHT = 3;
    public static int LEFT = 4;


    float fall = 0;
    public float fallSpeed = 2;
    public bool allowRotation = true;
    public bool limitRoatation = false; 
    public int individualScore = 100;
    private float individualScoreTime;
    private bool visited = false;
    private Tetromino[] connections = new Tetromino[4];


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        CheckUserInput ();
        UpdateIndividualScore ();
    }

    public void UpdateIndividualScore(){

        if (individualScoreTime < 1) {

            individualScoreTime += Time.deltaTime;

        } else {

            individualScoreTime = 0;

            individualScore = Mathf.Max (individualScore - 10, 0);
        }
    }
    public void CheckUserInput () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) {

            transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
            bool t = CheckIsValidPosition ();
            if (t) {

                FindObjectOfType<Game>().updateGrid(this);

            } else {

                transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
            }

        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {

            transform.position += new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
            bool t = CheckIsValidPosition ();
            if (t) {

                FindObjectOfType<Game>().updateGrid(this);

            } else {

                transform.position += new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
            }

        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Time.time - fall >= fallSpeed) {

            transform.position += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            bool t = CheckIsValidPosition ();
            //Debug.Log ("CHECK VALIDATION " + t);
            if (t) {

                FindObjectOfType<Game>().updateGrid(this);
                FindObjectOfType<Game> ().Checks ();

            } else {

                transform.position += new Vector3 (0, 1, 0);

                if (FindObjectOfType<Game> ().CheckIsAboveGrid (this)) 
                {
                    FindObjectOfType<Game> ().GameOver ();
                }
                    enabled = false;
                    FindObjectOfType<Game> ().SpawnNextTetromino ();
                    //FindObjectOfType<Game> ().updateConnection (this);
                    //FindObjectOfType<Game> ().Checks ();
                    Game.currentScore += individualScore;

            }
            fall = Time.time;
        }
    }


    bool CheckIsValidPosition () {

        foreach (Transform mino in transform) {

            Vector2 pos = FindObjectOfType<Game>().Round (mino.position);

            if (FindObjectOfType<Game>().CheckIsInsideGrid (pos) == false) {
                Debug.Log ("False 1");  
                return false;
            }

            Transform t = FindObjectOfType<Game> ().GetTransformAtGetPosition (pos);
            if (t != null) {
                if (t.parent != transform) {
                    Debug.Log ("False 3");
                    return false;
                }               
            }

            if (FindObjectOfType<Game>().GetTransformAtGetPosition(pos) != null && FindObjectOfType<Game>().GetTransformAtGetPosition(pos).parent != transform) {
                Debug.Log ("False 2");
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void setVisited(bool v){
        visited = v;
    }

    public bool isVisited(){
        return true;
    }

    public void setConnection(Tetromino t, int position){
        if (position == UP) {
            connections [0] = t;
        }
        if (position == DOWN) {
            connections [1] = t;
        }
        if (position == LEFT) {
            connections [2] = t;
        }
        if (position == RIGHT) {
            connections [3] = t;
        }
    }

    public Tetromino getTetrominoConnected(int position){
        if (position == UP) {
            return connections [0];
        }else if (position == DOWN) {
            return connections [1];
        }else if (position == LEFT) {
            return connections [2];
        }else {
            return connections [3];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: É melhor você dar uma enxugada no código, primeiro removendo os códigos comentados, e depois tirando as functions que não estão sendo executadas, pra ficar mais fácil a leitura e pra achar o problema

Comment: Não tenho certeza se esse é o motivo (seu código tá um tanto bagunçado e vc não explicoiu os detalhes dele), mas parece que a função `CheckIsAboveGrid` simplesmente verifica se o objeto está fora do grid *SEM VERIFICAR SE ELE JÁ SE ENCONTRA ENCAIXADO*. Sugestão: crie um flag para o objeto, e altere esse flag para verdadeiro apenas quando ele de fato encaixar no fundo. Então altere a tal função para retornar `true` somente se o objeto estiver fora do grid **E** também estiver encaixado.

Comment: @LuizVieira, "... retornar `true` somente se o objeto estiver fora do grid **E**" não estiver encaixado.

Comment: Bem observado, @MarceloUchimura. :) Tks